# ¿Existe o ha existido algún tratamiento de cortesía para la tercera persona del singular?

Tags: pronombres, solicitud-de-término, cortesía

En español existe una forma de tratamiento de cortesía para la primera persona del singular, denominada el [plural mayestático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_mayest%C3%A1tico), que consiste en usar *nos* en lugar de *yo*, usada especialmente por reyes y papas. Para la segunda persona tenemos varias opciones: usar *usted* o *vos* en lugar de *tú*. Sin embargo, no sé si existe o ha existido alguna forma de dar tratamiento de cortesía a una tercera persona que, al igual que en los dos primeros casos, no necesite de una mención expresa del nombre del aludido. Quiero decir, que siempre puedes dar cortesía a una tercera persona diciendo que "don Fulano de Tal me ha dicho que" en vez de simplemente "Fulano me ha dicho que". Mi pregunta va más por saber si hay alguna forma de sustituir *él* o *ella* en una frase para otorgar ese mismo tratamiento de cortesía que se da al *yo* y al *tú*.

¿Existe o ha existido un pronombre que pueda o haya podido cumplir esa función?

Comment: La página de la wiki que enlazas tiene la categoría [Fórmulas de tratamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:F%C3%B3rmulas_de_tratamiento) en las que se ve alguna interesante, especialmente dentro de la subcategoría [Tratamientos de la jerarquía nobiliaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:Tratamientos_de_la_jerarqu%C3%ADa_nobiliaria) y el anexo [Tratamientos protocolarios de la monarquía y la nobleza](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Tratamientos_protocolarios_de_la_monarqu%C3%ADa_y_la_nobleza), del tipo _Excelentísimo_, _Ilustrísimo_  o un mero _Señor_.

Comment: Podría decirse que hubo un germen de algo así: si usted viene de _vuestra merced_, también existió _su merced_. Quizá una de las razones para que uno evolucionara y el otro no sea que al ser ambas terceras personas una obliga a un cambio en la conjugación (tú eres/usted es) que lo hace más persistente (aparte de que tal vez haya tenido una frecuencia mucho mayor).

Comment: Curiosamente, **él** era un tratamiento formal de segunda persona por unos años (ni llegó a un siglo, tal vez un par de décadas), pero que sepa yo, nunca existió una forma así, aparte de —tal vez— el uso del mayúsculo en los pronombres divinos.

Answer (score 1):

Hombre, "haberlos haylos", no se desde cuándo, pero "haylos".

Después de trabajar 13 años en una administración de fincas, te puedo decir que no es tan raro escuchar a un conserje o un fontanero, y a otros como arquitectos, abogados, etcétera, decir cosas como "**el señor presidente** me ha dicho que arregle esto", o "**la señora** dice que se ha quedado sin luz"; en vez de usar el Don tal o la Doña cual. Y en los bares se puede oír todos los días "**el caballero** tomará una cerveza".
El uso de "señor", "señora", "señorita" y "caballero", es de lo más cotidiano cuando hablas con(o de) clientes o directamente alguien que no conoces o con quien no tienes confianza, aquí en Canarias más todavía, ya que hablamos siempre de usted y estas cosas ya salen solas por pura costumbre.
Es creencia popular muy extendida que los tratamientos de "señor" y "caballero" vienen de otras épocas cuando el señor era el dueño de un señorío, y el caballero pues eso, un caballero. Aunque yo no lo aseguraría a ciencia cierta.

Y hay más: a los jueces en el juzgado, su señoría; a los alcaldes, excelentísimo; a los pertenecientes a la familia real, su majestad...

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Nótese que en la pregunta indico que las fórmulas de cortesía pasan por usar expresiones como "don Fulano de Tal", o como las que indicas ("señor presidente", "el caballero"). Por supuesto, esas son fórmulas de cortesía perfectamente válidas, pero yo lo que estaba buscando más bien es un pronombre, igual que "nos" para la primera del singular, o "vos/usted" para la segunda del singular, sin tener que ceñirnos al español actual.

Comment: Es cierto, no es lo mismo que los pronombres. La verdad es que pensé que te referías a una alternativa a Don/Doña, y como esas fórmulas corresponden con la tercera persona con esa cortesía añadida y se usan normalmente como una sola palabra, como si fueran el "vos/usted", pues no lo pensé dos veces...